# Css class for Custom Content type fields

Tags: views, 7, nodes

I'm using seven theme for creating a basic pages. In that created more content types including title and body as shown in figure.  [image]

The page appear like this. 
[image]

Is it possible to add css class/styles for arranging beautiful manner. Like add custom css class for channel and language ..... How can I do this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module to control the wrappers of each field or add classes:

Drupal adds a lot of classes already, so you can probably look at the existing markup that Drupal is outputting and style it based on the classes that are already there.

Comment: Yeah tx for quick reply @Vincent. This class id displaying only in view page thats good enough for arranging data in view(like page). But what i want is arranging fields in add content page not in view page...

Comment: When in edit mode, there are edit-specific IDs you can use. For instance, on a field, you will see a wrapper ID like `edit-field-[field-name]`. You can use this to apply your styles.

Comment: Here I'm unable to add me custom css classes in manage fields level.